# listener for document whether it was closed

Tags: java, ms-word

Looking for a way to listen to a file being closed (eg. from Microsoft Word) from a Java application. No plugins/macros in the file itself. Would be possible to react on file changed but I need to know once its closed (and not only saved for example)

Comment: Not really easy as task as you will have to catch the event that the file opened ( so you will know for what file you are looking for ) or monitor the same directory for the `~.lock` file Word uses to store changes and prevent file corruption. It really depends on the system